# How do I prove that if one set in a pair of reciprocal sets is basis the other is also a basis?

Tags: vector-spaces

If $U=\{ u_1,\cdots,u_n\}$ and $W=\{ w_1,\cdots,w_n\}$ are reciprocal sets ($u_i\cdot w_j=\delta_{ij}$) in a Hilbert Space $V$ where $U$ is a basis, how can I prove that $W$ is also a basis? I have already proved that $W$ is linear independent, but I can't get $span(W)=V$. Could anyone help?

Comment: These are finite sets, $U$ is a basis, $W$ is the same size and its vectors are linearly independent, so you're done...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't remember this basic property!! Thank you very much for your answer and for reminding me.